# How to reliably tell which maven plugin fails a Jenkins build?

Tags: maven, jenkins

So in Jenkins I'm using a variety of useful plugins like Cobertura, Emma etc, all of which are likely to fail for various reasons.

In general these plugins have terrible error reporting so it's often not possible to easily tell which plugin failed the build. Usually all I'll see is a subsequent message from another plugin saying it's not going to do anything because the build had been previously marked as FAILED by some other plugin, but there's often no indication of who that other plugin is.

Is there a way to get maven to actually identify which plugin failed a build, when the plugins themselves fail to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on Maven debug output using -X flag with mvn command and -e flag to enable full execution error messages.